# SOLR facet with prefix and filters

Tags: solr, facet

I have a problem with using facet.

I need autocomplete and for this I using facet:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=on&facet=on&rows=0&fq=filter:("30")  AND filter2:("1")&facet.field=spell&facet.prefix=g&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1
```

I am using facet because I need to add filters to query for example **filter:("30")  AND filter2:("1")**

When I have in index a few documents all working fine and fast but if I add a lot of documents into index this query working too slow or simply SOLR is not responding at this query.

My schema.xml:

```
......
<fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
.....
<fields>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
   <field name="article" type="textSpellShingle" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="filter" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="filter2" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>article</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
<copyField source="article" dest="spell"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="spell"/>
....
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question exactly?

Comment: Yep, what's the actual question?

Comment: I asked but then I found solution. And since I can not answer on my question within 8 hours, I edited it and added the answer.

Comment: I found the problem I simply added **facet.method=enum** and now it's work fine. Also I removed **fq=filter:("30") AND filter2:("1")** and place it in query, so... query now looks like this one:

    http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=filter:("30") AND filter2:("1")&wt=json&indent=on&facet=on&rows=0&facet.field=spell&facet.prefix=g&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.method=enum

Comment: @vladimir Ok, good to know. Can I ask what's the reason for using shingle with a field on which you use facet with facet.prefix parameter?

Comment: @javanna Sorry I am not guru of SOLR and I took this example from somewhere(not remember). Do you mean I don't need to using shingle for this field? Thanks.

Comment: @vladimir I wouldn't use it, I was wondering if your usecase requires it. You can always try removing it, reindexing your data and see what happens :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem I simply added facet.method=enum and now it's work fine. Also I removed fq=filter:("30") AND filter2:("1") and place it in query, so... query now looks like this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=filter:("30") AND filter2:("1")&wt=json&indent=on&facet=on&rows=0&facet.field=spell&facet.prefix=g&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.method=enum
```